# How to remove draw value in a barChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using the stacked barchart of the MPAndroidChart library. Does anyone know how to remove the value that appears on the top of the each bar ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can remove values by calling:

`barData.setDrawValues(false)`

It's also in the [documentation](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/chartdata/).